# How do I return more than one sql table for Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to return multiple tables from the MySQL database under one router, but whatever I try it seems like I can't get it to return multiple values, right now if I change the result.then I can get one of the tables to return, I want to have both tables return at the same time.

my code for executing SQL

```
function exec(sql) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
                return
            }
            resolve(result)
        })
    })
  return promise
}
```

my code for the functions:

```
const getCluster1 = (list) =>{
    let sql = `select * from demoClusterDescription where 1=1 `
    
    return exec(sql)

}
const getCluster2 = (list) =>{
    let sql = `select * from prefClusterDescription where 1=1 `
    
    return exec(sql)

}
```

my code for the return

```
router.get('/demo', function(req,res,next)  {
    
    const { list } = req.query
    const result1 = getCluster1(list)
    const result2 = getCluster2(list)

    
    return result1.then(cluster => {
      res.json(
         new SuccessModel(cluster)
      )
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself a few headaches and drop the old school `.then()` syntax in favour of `async/await` style :

```
router.get('/demo', async function(req,res,next)  {
    
    const { list } = req.query
    const result1 = await getCluster1(list)
    const result2 = await getCluster2(list)

    console.log("result1 = ", result1)
    console.log("result2 = ", result2)
    
    // Do something with them

})
```